# How can I view a .docx document using dark mode on Android?

Tags: dark-mode

How can I view a .docx document using dark mode on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Android 11 *(Not sure about lower versions if they have the system-wide dark theme)* and system-wide dark theme is enabled. Google Docs will open the document in dark mode.

*It'll be helpful if you provide more details about your device.*

Answer (score 0):

[Firelord**♦**](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277/firelord) mentioned that [WPS Office](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WPS_Office) allows users to view a .docx document using dark mode on Android:

> Wps office supports night mode which acts as dark mode actually, though you have to enable it explicitly for every document. – [Firelord**♦**](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277/firelord) [Jun 7 '20 at 4:20](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225717/how-can-i-view-a-docx-document-using-dark-mode-on-android#comment294025_225717)